# Setting Clang as default compiler used in pip install on Windows

Tags: python, c, compiler-errors, cython

Visual Studio 2017 now ships with `clang`, and I was wondering if it is possible to set `clang` to be the default compiler used when trying to install a python package with `Cython` dependencies via `pip install`.

As far as I can tell the issue seems to be that `pip` doesn't know where to look for `clang`; it defaults to the path containing the `MSVC` compiler to compile the `.c` files specified in the package `setup.py`. Is there any way I can either 1) set the path to the compiler to be used, or 2) specify that `clang` should be used explicitly?

I'm working on Windows 10, using the Anaconda distribution and Python 3.6. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What you could possibly do is download the package with `pip download package_name` and then modify the `setup.py` file to use `clang` before installing it locally.

Comment: How would I go about modifying `setup.py` to use `clang`?

Answer (score 4):

Do not do it.

It *can* be done on the command line by setting compiler:

`python setup.py build_ext -c <compiler>`

`python setup.py build_ext --help-compiler` to see available options.

**However**, the same compiler used to build the python distribution **must** be used for all extensions as the extension modules will be loaded by the interpreter.

If they are built by a different compiler, **they cannot be safely loaded** by the python interpreter.

In the case of Anaconda, its python distribution is built with MSVC, so the same compiler used by the anaconda environment should be used for extensions. In that case, activating the anaconda environment should suffice, though compiler can be set explicitly as above.

See [Windows Compilers python wiki entry](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers).

Comment: yes! although Anaconda still uses MSVC on windows, not GCC (https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-windows.html#microsoft-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing that out. The issue here is that the module I'm trying to build require a C99-compliant compiler; running the build with MSVC (which to my understanding is not C99-compliant) results in error regarding variable length arrays and others, which is why I wanted to use `clang`. Any suggestions on how about to go about building it then?

Additionally, running `python setup.py build_ext -c clang` returns an error `error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'nt' with 'clang' compiler`. Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: `python setup.py build_ext --help-compiler` to see what compilers setuptools is able to choose from. It may be it just does not have clang support, tho it may be possible to use `CC=clang` variable and `-c unix`. For C99 support, later versions of MSVC do support it, but VS 9 (2008) does not which is required for Python 2.7. If you need support for that and C99 at the same time, windows is not an option.

Comment: Right - also depending on exactly which part of C99 noncompliance is an issue, there are plenty of hacks/workarounds floating around the internet - e.g. a `<stdint.h>` replacement that's often useful - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3cb64bd2953fd264a3d0762806e800f58800641d/pandas/_libs/src/headers/ms_stdint.h

Comment: Sorry for raising this thread back from the dead. The errors I'm getting are `error C2057: expected constant expression`, `cannot allocate an array of constant size 0` and `unknown size` when attempting to compile with `MSVC` that ships with VS2017. Is this still an issue with C99 compilance, or am I moving in the wrong direction here?

Comment: @danny additionally, I tried `set CC=clang` and compiling with the `--compiler=unix` flag, to no avail; I get an even weirder error:

`File "C:\Users\anant_000\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 211, in customize_compiler
    archiver = ar + ' ' + ar_flags
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`